# Kubernetes Network Policy stops all traffic to Pod

Tags: networking, kubernetes, policy

Scenario:

1. I have Four(4) Pods, Payroll,internal,external,mysql.
2. I want internal pod to only access:

   - a. Internal > Payroll on port 8080
   - b. Internal > mysql on port 3306

Kindly suggest what is missing part? I made the below network policy. But my pod is unable to communicate with 'any' pod.
Hence it has achieved the given target, but practically unable to access other pods. Below are my network policy details.

```
master $ k describe netpol/internal-policy
Name:         internal-policy
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2020-02-20 02:15:06 +0000 UTC
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     name=internal
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: 8080/TCP
    To:
      PodSelector: name=payroll
    ----------
    To Port: 3306/TCP
    To:
      PodSelector: name=mysql
  Policy Types: Egress
```

Policy YAML

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: payroll
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: mysql
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 3306 (edited)
```

Comment: Are the labels on mysql and payroll correct?

Comment: What about the CNI that is responsible for implementing your network policies ? What solution are you using ?

Comment: Yes pods are labelled correctly.
Yes, some network policy plugin is in place that's why after creating this policy pods are unable to communicate. I access the virtual K8s cluster in kodekloud.com (its via katakoda)

Answer (score 0):

> Hence it has achieved the given target, but practically unable to
>   access other pods.

If I understand you correctly you achieved the goal defined in your **network policy** and all your `Pods` wearing label `name: internal` are currently able to communicate both with `payroll` (on port `8080`) and `mysql` (on port `3306`) `Pods`, right ?

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I see some contradiction in your statement. On the one hand you want your `internal` `Pods` to be able to communicate only with very specific set of `Pods` and connect with them using specified ports:

> I want internal pod to only access:
>
> a. Internal > Payroll on port 8080
>
> b. Internal > mysql on port 3306

and on the other, you seem surprised that they can't access any other `Pods`:

> Hence it has achieved the given target, but practically unable to
>   access other pods.

Keep in mind that when you apply some `NetworkPolicy` rule on specific set of `Pods`, at the same time the dafault **deny all** rule is implicitly applied on selected `Pods` (unless you decide to reconfigure the [default policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-policies) to make it work the way you want).

As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#isolated-and-non-isolated-pods):

> Pods become isolated by having a NetworkPolicy that selects them. Once
>   there is any NetworkPolicy in a namespace selecting a particular pod,
>   that pod will reject any connections that are not allowed by any
>   NetworkPolicy. (Other pods in the namespace that are not selected by
>   any NetworkPolicy will continue to accept all traffic.)

The above applies also to `egress` rules.

If currently your `internal` `Pods` have access only to `payroll` and `mysql` `Pod` on specified `ports`, everything works as it is supposed to work.

If you are interested in denying all other traffic to your `payroll` and `mysql` `Pods`, you should apply an `ingress` rule on those `Pods` rather than defining `egress` on `Pods` which are supposed to communicate with them, but at the same time they should not be deprived of the ability to communicate with other `Pods`.

Please let me know if it helped. If something is not clear or my assumption was wrong, also please let me know and don't hesitate to ask additional questions.